# How i can sort date in table using Antd?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I tried to sort the date using `sorter` like this `sorter: (a, b) => moment(a.Modified).unix() - moment(b.Modified).unix(),`

and this my date after request  `{moment(item?.lastModifiedDate || item.createdDate).format('DD.MM.YYYY HH.mm')}`

it's showing the  arrows up and down but doesn't do any thing

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add more exemple like a codesandbox to help us.

Comment: sure i will add some screen shoot and if anyone how what is the type of the columnsType let me know

Comment: Since you are using `moment` already? why not use `.isAfter` or `IsBefore` for much accurate instead of manually subtracting the date.

Comment: did you make sure `Modified` has consistent date format? Inconsistent format may result in wrong type and antd wouldn't sort it.

Comment: i fix it,need to be sorted from endpoint

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem with this;

```
sorter: (a, b) => moment(a).valueOf() - moment(b).valueOf()
```

Comment: I think this should be:
sorter: (a, b) => moment(a.Modified).valueOf() - moment(b.Modified).valueOf()

Answer (score -1):

with datefns you can do:
`sorter: (a, b) => isBefore(new Date(a.date), new Date(b.date)) ? -1 : 1`